# I am facing a very awkward situation in C

Tags: c

In this code, the value of `rr` is working properly only when i am using the `printf` statement, otherwise the code is entering into the while loop even if `rr` is actually an integer value, for example `rr = 2.0`.

[My full code here](http://pastebin.com/qriQ8i23)

```
    double rr = log(c)/log(2);
    printf("Current value of rr is %lf\n",rr);


    while(!(rr == (int)rr))
    {
        printf("hung in loop with c = %d\n",c);

            if(c % 2 == 0)
                c = c/2;
            else
                c = (c-1)/2;
            rr = log(c)/log(2);
            cc++;

    }
```

This is the weirdest problem i have ever faced. The question is codechef august challenge problem 1.

Comment: One problem might be that you're doing [floating point equality comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17333/3425536).

Comment: When `rr` is `2.0` you now that it is likely that it's not *exactly* `2.0` in binary, right? It might be `1.99999997` or `2.00000012`. Floating point values are not exactly precise.

Comment: but just ading a printf statement solves the problem!

Comment: @SauravMukherjee Not my vote but one reason could be that the title is not very descriptive.

Comment: @SauravMukherjee If adding a `printf` makes it work then you've almost certainly got undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: Do a couple of things. Search Stackoverflow for "floating point precision". There are numerous problems posted in that area. Also, read, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @zenith, can u explain a little bit further, or any articles will be much appreciated.

Comment: @SauravMukherjee Don't be newbie, instead [RTFM](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: alright, will keep it in mind from next time. ty

Comment: As an aside, in C, there's an inequality operator. So instead of `!(a == b)` you just use `a != b`. As noted above, however, *exact* comparison of float values with other values is not generally going to do what you expect due to resolution of the fractional part representation in the machine.

Comment: Thank guys, i kept the difference range within the limit of 0.001 and it works now. However, it was still a pretty weird problem to have! :p

Comment: @lurker, i know. But  what's the difference between !(a == b) and (a != b) ?

Comment: Semantically they mean the same thing. If the first case, you are testing for equality and logically negating the result. In the second, you are testing for inequality.

Comment: When `rr` is a `double`, when you compare `rr = (int)rr`, C is going to cast the `rr` on the right to an `int` and it will truncate it. So it might result in an integer value of `1` or of `2` depending upon whether `rr` value of 2.0 is really 1.999999something, or 2.000000something. Then, to compare with `rr` again, it will take that result of `1` or `2` and promote it (recast it) to a `double` to compare like types. I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but this construct is most likely not doing what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in lurker's comment, this is not doing what you expect:

```
while(!(rr == (int)rr))
```

A better method would be:

```
while((rr - floor(rr)) > .0001)
```

This avoids casting and accounts for the fact that floating point is not always an exact representation.

Comment: Can someone delete the post, because the original code is present her, and i don't want someone(a random guy) to copy paste my code as  a result of which i might be disqualified.